# How remove banner adView from a Screen in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have an AdMob banner in the game. But I need this banner not to be shown in `Screen_1` and when user enter `Screen_2` I need to show the banner.
When I call `AdView.gone()` it dissapears from screen but coordinates becomes wrong and touch position doesn't match with coordinates. How can I properly remove `AdView`.

Comment: have you tried AdView.Remove()?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too but after that coordinates becomes wrong all the same.

Comment: Try creating something that stores the cords, then call it when its called for creation.

Answer (score 1):

First, in the class with the Activity, create a new `Handler` instance and override the method `handleMessage(Message msg)`.
Then, create two constants

```
private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
private  final int HIDE_ADS = 0;
```

Pretty much, the `Message` has a variable called `what` with some information that you'll use for a switch line. This switch line will have to test if, what was passed in, is telling the method to display or hide the ad. It should look like this:

```
handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);

                switch (msg.what){
                    case SHOW_ADS:
                        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case (HIDE_ADS):
                        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

After you did that, you'll need to be able to call this from outside the main thread.
The best way to call this method from outside the main thread is like this:

First, create a new interface with the method `showAds(boolean show)` and **make `AndroidLauncher` implement it (or whatever your Main Activity is called)**

```
public interface AdHandler{
    public void showAds(boolean show);
}
```

The overridden method in the class with the Main Activity (most likely AndroidLauncher) has to just relay the message to the `handleMessage()` method because you can't call the method directly:

```
@Override
    public void showAds(boolean show) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
    }
```

The final step is to pass the class itself into your main Gdx class

```
initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(this), config);
```

From there you can use the `showAds()` method whenever and wherever you want (you'll have to pass the variable around yourself).